# How do I connect my business's Instagram account to its Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-pages, instagram

I've just created a business account on Instagram for my business. I am now trying to connect the Instagram account to my business's Facebook page. I am the Facebook page's only administrator.

I'm trying to follow these instructions from [Meta's own documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/345675946300334?id=419087378825961), which states - in part:

1. Go to your Instagram profile.
2. Select Edit Profile.
3. Under Public Business Information, Select Page.

This is where I'm getting lost. I've converted the account to a business account, but as shown below, **there is no "Public Business Information" section.**

How do I connect my business's Instagram account to its Facebook page?

[image: Instagram "Edit Profile" screen]